# Sha1 restrictions not working properly for Android Key on google cloud Platform

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, android-security

I have implemented **sha1** restriction on my AndroidKey in google cloud platform.
But i can use same Android Key in other project and feature like google analytics and youtube and many more are working with same key on different project that having different keystore.

So, my question is what exactly **SHA1** restriction does if i am able to use android key in different project also.

Comment: SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm 1) is a cryptographic hash function and it is not for security,  but to identify revisions and to ensure that the data has not changed due to accidental corruption.

Comment: but google is recommending SHA1 as a security.
Go on this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/get-api-key